# How to display all three letters in the array?

Tags: javascript

code:

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
 for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){
 alert (a[i]);
```

Currently I am getting only 'c' in the alert. I want to get all three of them. How do I do?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/937h2qvr/. The error is somewhere else. By the way, you didn't close the bracket.

Comment: That said, if you're not declaring `i` anywhere, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (it'll still run, though, in loose mode).

Comment: do you want to alert like "abc"? Because your code should do what you want

Comment: I want it to display in a list like this:  `<li> a </li> <li> b </li> <li> c </li>`

Comment: Yes I first tried with li and it did not work so I tried with alert and it did not work. Had missed the }

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `alert` line and watch how your program behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an error or do you want to see all elements in array?
https://jsfiddle.net/937h2qvr/1/

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
var result="";
 for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){
 result += " " + a[i];  
}
alert (result);
```

**UPDATED** (added li)

https://jsfiddle.net/937h2qvr/2/

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
var result="";

for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(a[i]); 
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("arrayShow").appendChild(node); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = " ";
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 alert(   text += "<li>" + a[i] + "</li>");
}
```

be sure, it works.